# How to make object awaitable in python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have a pseudo async generator which actually fetches all needed data on the initialisation. And I want to iterate over it with `async for`. My simplified code looks like this:

```
class MyObject:
  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name

  def operate(self):
     pass

class MyGenerator:    
  def __init__(self, params):
    self.params = params
    self.current = 0
    self.last = None
    self.data = None

  async def make_http_request(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 42

  async def fetch_data(self):
    # actually it is not comprehentions since async comprehentions 
    # are not available in 3.5. It is a simple loop with await's
    return [MyObject(i) for i in self.make_http_request()]

  def __aiter__(self):
    self.data = await self.fetch_data()
    return self  

  def __anext__(self):
    try:
       result = self.data[self.current]
    except IndexError:
      raise StopAsyncIteration
    self.current += 1

    return result
```

If I run this code with `async for x in MyGenerator()`, I will get `"TypeError: 'async for' received an invalid object from __anext__: MyObject"`.

So looks like async generator should return awaitable object. So the question is - how can I make "classic" object awaitable? Looks like I should implement `__await__` method and looks like this method should return iterator object, but how can I make iterator for actually not iterable object?

Comment: `return = [MakeObject() for i in make_http_request()]` causes SyntaxError

Comment: please provide **all** the code ([minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: always put in question full error message.

Comment: I updated the question, thx for you comments.

Comment: if you merely need to make http requests, use `aiohttp`

Comment: @AminEtesamian yes, I know about itm but my problem is not about making http requests but about `async for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

`__anext__` ["Must return an **awaitable**"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__anext__). Currently it would return a `MyObject()`.  I have changed your `self.fetch_data()` below - check out this example to demonstrate 3 generators running asynchronously:

```
import asyncio

import random


class MyGenerator:
    async def make_http_request(self):
        n = random.uniform(0.1, 3)
        await asyncio.sleep(n)
        return n

    def fetch_data(self):
        return [self.make_http_request() for i in range(5)]

    def __aiter__(self):
        self.current = 0
        self.data = self.fetch_data()
        return self

    def __anext__(self):
        # print("anext")
        try:
            task = self.data[self.current]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.current += 1

        return task


async def main(tag):
    print(tag, "start")
    async for x in MyGenerator():
        print(tag, x)
    print(tag, "done")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(main("A"), main("B"), main("C")))
loop.close()

print('done')
```